# How to track the email whether has been opened by end user

Tags: asp.net, email, web

I got a especial requirement is track the email whether has been opened by end user.

Logic is :

1. asp.net program got user email address list from database
2. send email notification to users based on that address list
3. when user open the email, the sender(web site server) will get a request or update to mark the record has been read in database

I don't owns the mail server, so maybe use hotmail\gmail to send email notification.

Based on my description, anyone can help me out? Or let me know if this can be implemented?
Many thanks and kindly show me your ideas!

Comment: you can request reading receipt when sending email like this: email.Headers.Add("Read-Receipt-To","somebody@somewhere") but there is no guarantee the mail client will support it

Answer (score 2):

Often, you put a blank img with size 1*1 on the mail, with any parameter you want (like img src: `http://{website}/Controller/TrackingImage/{userid}`). When the user open the mail, it loads the img and you get the request on your webserver.

But drawback is that user often have to accept images in mails, so it wont work in most of cases.

Comment: right, this solution need user to accept to show the image, so this is limited for most of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Email open tracking by 1x1 image pixel tracking won't work in Yahoo mail and Hotmail when they open through web interface in this case you can fix this by using  HTML5 video element

```
<video width='1' height='1' controls='controls'> 
 <source src='YourDomain.com/openEmail?userID=xxx@hotmail.com&title=weekend-offer'/>
</video>
```

When  end your open email it will request the videos there by send open information together user email id 
this one will work in Hotmail and yahoo mail but don't work in gmail

Comment: thanks, I have implemented this by using IhttpModule interface. here the reference : http://www.aspnetemail.com/samples/emailtracker/

Comment: will this solution work in Gmail , hotmail ? these email service show the image from their servers .